# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FMILEAGEBALANCE"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I've created a store procedure for a particular query.

```
--First Stored Procedure--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetMileageBalance (StartMileage IN NUMBER,EndMileage IN NUMBER, ExpDate IN DATE)
IS  
 --Code declaration section--
--variables to store column values returned from select into
 fPassengerID        VARCHAR2(10);
 pFirst              VARCHAR2(20);
 pLast               VARCHAR2(20);
 fFreqflyernum       NUMBER (10);
 fFreqflyerMileage   NUMBER (7);
 fMileagebalance     NUMBER (7);
 fMileageExpDate     DATE;
 MileageExpDate      DATE;
 MileageStart        NUMBER (7);
 MileageEnd          NUMBER (7);
 MileageBalance      NUMBER (7);

BEGIN --Code execution section
          --executing select into Query assign to variable
          --MileageExpDate := '01/OCT/2017';--
          --MileageStart := 10000;--
          --MileageEnd :=  20000;--

SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, 
F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
INTO  fPassengerID,    
pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage,fMileagebalance,fMileageExpDate
FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
WHERE F.MileageBalance >= StartMileage AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= EndMileage
AND MileageExpDate > ExpDate;

--Displaying the results
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CUSTOMER INFORMATION: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  ' ||fPassengerID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('First Name of passenger is:  ' ||pFirst);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Last Name of passenger is:  ' ||pLast);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: ' ||fFreqflyernum);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  ' ||fFreqflyerMileage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageBalance );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageExpDate);

END sp_GetMileageBalance;
```

When executing it, I would get something like this for example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

EXECUTE sp_GetMileageBalance (10000,20000,'01-OCT-17');

CUSTOMER INFORMATION: 
The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  KL87DF34DS
First Name of passenger is:  Michelle
Last Name of passenger is:  Mullington
Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: 9374392018
Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  400
Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  15000
Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  19-DEC-20


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is the table where I'm extracting the information:

[Table being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWYAr.png)

If I was to go ahead and try to extract information that returned more than one record, it will tell me that I'm not allowed to. So, I decided to see if I could use a cursor within a store procedure to do this.

This is what I attempted to do:

```
--First Stored Procedure--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_GetMileageBalance (StartMileage IN     
NUMBER,EndMileage IN NUMBER, ExpDate IN DATE)
IS  --Code declaration section--
--variables to store column values returned from select into
 fPassengerID        VARCHAR2(10);
 pFirst              VARCHAR2(20);
 pLast               VARCHAR2(20);
 fFreqflyernum       NUMBER (10);
 fFreqflyerMileage   NUMBER (7);
 fMileagebalance     NUMBER (7);
 fMileageExpDate     DATE;
 MileageExpDate      DATE;
 MileageStart        NUMBER (7);
 MileageEnd          NUMBER (7);
 MileageBalance      NUMBER (7);

  --Declare Cursor
          CURSOR cur_FreqFlyer IS
 --Query cursor will point to results         
SELECT F.FPASSENGERID, P.First, P.Last, F.FREQFLYERNUM, F.FREQFLYERMILEAGE, 
F.MILEAGEBALANCE, F.MILEAGEEXPDATE
INTO  fPassengerID,   
pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage,fMileagebalance,fMileageExpDate
FROM FREQUENT_FLYER F
INNER JOIN PASSENGER P
ON F.FPassengerID = P.PassengerID
WHERE F.MileageBalance >= StartMileage AND F.MILEAGEBALANCE <= EndMileage
AND MileageExpDate > ExpDate;

      --Start Execution section
BEGIN 
     --Open Cursor
     OPEN cur_FreqFlyer; --  open cursor for use   
     --loop to display each record returned by cursor 
     --Use PL/SQL language control or loop to display each record pointed by  cursor 
   LOOP
        --Fetch cursor data
        FETCH cur_FreqFlyer INTO    
fPassengerID,pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage 
   fMileageBalance,fMileageExpDate;
    EXIT WHEN cur_FreqFlyer%NOTFOUND;
        --Display each record
        --Displaying the results
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CUSTOMER INFORMATION: ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The Frequent Flyer PassengerID is:  ' ||fPassengerID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('First Name of passenger is:  ' ||pFirst);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Last Name of passenger is:  ' ||pLast);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer number of passenger is: ' ||fFreqflyernum);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Mileage of Passenger is:  ' ||fFreqflyerMileage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Frequent Flyer Balance of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageBalance );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Mileage expiration date of passenger is:  ' ||fMileageExpDate);

END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_FreqFlyer; --close cursor
```

When I did that, it gave me this error:

```
    Error(36,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FMILEAGEBALANCE" when   
    expecting one of the following:     . ( , % ; limit The symbol "." was   
    substituted for "FMILEAGEBALANCE" to continue.
```

I'm trying to determine why it's giving me this error.

Comment: Missing a comma after fFreqflyerMileage in the Fetch statement.  `FETCH cur_FreqFlyer INTO    
fPassengerID,pFirst,pLast,fFreqflyernum,fFreqflyerMileage  --<MISSING COMMA 
   fMileageBalance,fMileageExpDate;`  Voting to close as offtopic typographical..  I get it; you stare at this stuff long enough sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.  Missing comma between Line 16-17 from bottom (inclusive of spaces)